# Can't click on obj or link for payment in pop-up cart

Tags: html, selenium, robotframework

This problem is specification on RobotFramework(Selenium) language.
I would like to Click on button ("i.stack.imgur.com/PTNYl.jpg") after confirm purchasing

For clear information please see below picture with ordered number

1. Select 2 items.
2. Click "สั่งซื้อ" (confirm purchasing).
3. Pop-up of cart will show about description and Payment button image.

([Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8SaW.jpg))

**Website :** "www.tarad.com/product/5807261#cart"

**Code :** (saved to .txt and run on Command Prompt)

```
Open Browser    http://www.tarad.com/product/5807261#cart    chrome
Select From List By Value    product_qty    2
Click Button    f_buy
Wait Until Page Contains Element    xpath=//*[@id="flyout_cart"]/div[6]/a/
Click Link    xpath=//*[@id='flyout_cart']/div[6]/a/span[@id='btn-payment']
```

([click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzj8T.jpg))

I can find this pop-up cart description, but can't click on button for payment, moreover, I try using Click Image, Click Link, Click Element with payment button xpath that got from Chrome Browser.

I apologize about my English writing and thank you to your attention.

Comment: Do you get an error when you try clicking on the element? Or does it pass but actually doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Goralight This's  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzj8T.jpg

Comment: I'm not allowed to view images, can you post the error in text format please?

Comment: @Goralight ValueError: Element locator 'xpath//*[@id='flyout_cart']/div[6]/a/span[@id='btn-payment']' did not match any elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the Click Link and Click Image, if you are not sure the underlying element is that type - use the general Click Element. Looking at the locator you've specified, the target is a span, so Element should do.

Regretfully I cannot open the site right now to check the html (mobile...), but as far the locator you are using:

- do not use indexed paths - the div[6] up there - if the page structure changes just slightly, they can easily brake (which is probably the case with your run)
- try not to use direct descendants (the single /) except if you're not sure the structure will remain the same in the long run - they are much faster than "any descent down" - i.e. //, but again, if the structure changes in a future build, they will break. For good or bad, these two negatives are what browsers generate when you ask them to create an xpath
- finally, I see in your sample the target span has an id attribute - that is (almost always) the safest and fastest locator strategy to use. So remove everything before it, and address the element as "id=btn-payment"

E.g. change the last call to

```
Click Element    id=btn-payment
```

Hope this will resolve it for you

Comment: Sniped... Yeah you was using the wrong Keywords. I tend to always use `Click Element` Also, you was over complicating things, you had the ID ready to use, with no need for xpaths. This test case worked for me:     `Open Browser    http://www.tarad.com/product/5807261#cart    chrome`
    `Select From List By Value    product_qty    2`
    `Click Button    f_buy`
    `Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=icon-cart`
    `Click Element    id=icon-cart`
    `Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=btn-payment`
    `Click Element    id=btn-payment`

Comment: @Goralight I hope you are addressing OP, cause you were using "you" as a comment to my answer :D

Comment: @Todor Yeah meant OP - sorry :P

Comment: No worries, I found it funny :)